# How to resume a Visual Studio 2017 intentionally stopped

Tags: visual-studio, offline

I started downloading Visual Studio for offline installation using layout switch. When the installation was 19.1Go, I closed the console and the download got stopped. Today I restarted it in the same folder (where previous files were) thinking it would continue. However, from what I see, it simply overwrites the previous files (files are still downloaded from internet). So, I am wondering if someone has a way to make it continue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

simple retype the command after opening command prompt in my case it was `vs_community.exe --layout c:\vs2017layout --lang en-US` 
**NOTE directory should be same as previous**
it first verify the previously downloaded packages and then resumed the downloading here are some logs

```
Verified existing package 'Microsoft.VisualC.140.CRT.Redist.X86.Msi,version=14.0.24225'
Verified existing package 'Microsoft.VisualC.140.CRT.Source.Msi,version=14.0.24225'
Verified existing package 'Microsoft.VisualC.140.CRT.x64.Desktop.Msi,version=14.0.24225'
Verified existing package 'Microsoft.VisualC.140.CRT.x64.OneCore.Desktop.Msi,version=14.0.24225'
Verified existing package 'Microsoft.VisualC.140.CRT.x64.Store.Msi,version=14.0.24225'
Verified existing package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.OfficeDeveloperTools.WIF.WindowsFeature,version=15.0.26621.2'
Total packages to download: 307
Starting 'UpdateLayout' operation
Download of 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/10661194/7385009d7cc46622284fa28aea9a82bf/netfx45_dtp.msi' succeeded using engine 'WebClient'
Download of 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/10715705/f34cc4a1fd105b0276170faf7f5e0271/VC_CRT.X86.Desktop.msi' succeeded using engine 'WebClient'
Download of 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/10715705/f34cc4a1fd105b0276170faf7f5e0271/cab2.cab' succeeded using engine 'WebClient'Download of 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/10661194/7385009d7cc46622284fa28aea9a82bf/netfx45_dtp.cab' succeeded using engine 'Bits'
UpdateLayout progress: 0.06%
Download of 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/10715069/2f1ac63ac0488abe845c76ad6690d8c9/VC_CRT.X86.OneCoreDesktop.msi' succeeded using engine 'Bits'
Download of 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/10715705/f34cc4a1fd105b0276170faf7f5e0271/cab1.cab' succeeded using engine 'WebClient'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes , now we can resume the  offline installation. Latest installer Verifies the files if directory is unchanged and Resumes from there But they should provide torrent links of at least VS community edition, it is more reliable especially if files are multiple and are large in size.